# python 3.5 install pyscard in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python-3.5, pyscard, raspbian-stretch

i have try to install pyscard in python 3.5, but always getting error

[error install pyscard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEEgP.png)

anyone can helo me?

Comment: Please insert an error message as text, not an image.

Comment: ok sorry im a new one using stackoverflow hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer in here:
http://raspberrypi4u.blogspot.com/2018/01/raspberry-pi-smartcard-reader-thai-id.html

an as a sample code is here:
sudo apt-get install pcscd git python-setuptools swig gcc libpcsclite-dev python-dev

git clone https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pyscard.git
cd pyscard
sudo python setup.py build_ext install
sudo reboot